# Any advantages in putting code in build.scala over build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

From what I understand build.sbt and build.scala get merged during a compile.

Are there any advantages on going with one or the other (or both!)?

Answer (score 1):

Describing projects in .scala files is deprecated, and won't be supported in the foreseeable future.

Sticking to .sbt files has the distinct advantage of being future-proof.

Answer (score -1):

The recommended approach is to define settings in `.sbt` files, using `.scala` files when you need to factor out a `val` or `object` or method definition

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html

Comment: I downvoted : because .scala files aren't recommended in any way anymore, since they are deprecated, I don't think this is a good answer.

Comment: That's what I remembered too, but I could not find a quote fast enough. Here's something that confirms that as of sbt 0.13, build.scala is deprecated https://github.com/lastland/scala-forklift/issues/19